# Why does this decorator calls "TypeError: make_sandwich() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"

Tags: python, python-2.7

so I got around to messing with classes and decorators but I can't seem to get past this error: *TypeError: make_sandwich() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)*

I tried doing all of it outside of a class and it works. Any ideas on how to make this work inside my sandwich maker?

```
class SandwichMaker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sandwich = []
        self.bread = "========"
        self.bacon = " ~~~~~~ "
        self.olives = " oooooo "

    def make_sandwich(self, insides):
        def add_bread():
            self.sandwich.insert(0, self.bread)
            insides()
            self.sandwich.append(self.bread)
        return add_bread

    def add_bacon(self):
        return self.bacon

    def add_olives(self):
        return self.olives

    @make_sandwich
    def print_sandwich(self):
        for i in range(len(self.sandwich)):
            print self.sandwich[i]

my_sandwich = SandwichMaker()
my_sandwich.add_olives()
my_sandwich.add_bacon()
my_sandwich.print_sandwich()
```

edit: hey, so I fixed it thanks to the answers. If anyone wants to grab a fully working, nonsense sandwich printer, below is the final version:

```
def make_sandwich(insides):
    def add_bread(self):
        bread = "========"
        print bread
        insides(self)
        print bread
    return add_bread

class SandwichMaker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sandwich = []
        self.bacon = " ~~~~~~ "
        self.olives = " oooooo "

    def add_bacon(self):
        self.sandwich.append(self.bacon)

    def add_olives(self):
        self.sandwich.append(self.olives)

    @make_sandwich
    def print_sandwich(self):
        for i in range(len(self.sandwich)):
            print self.sandwich[i]

my_sandwich = SandwichMaker()
my_sandwich.add_bacon()
my_sandwich.add_olives()
my_sandwich.add_bacon()
my_sandwich.add_bacon()
my_sandwich.print_sandwich()
```

Comment: Because it's `@make_sandwich(insides)`

Comment: This makes no sense to me. The "insides" is created within the decorator, and should take the print_sandwich() as it's value AFAIK.

Comment: Then it should be `def make_sandwich(insides)`. The `self` is irrelevant - It should be out of the class, because it's not really a part of the `SandwichMaker`. Try it.

Comment: @Zizouz212: You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @Pretzel Will do... But I now see two other answers. :/

Comment: @Zizouz212: Missed your opportunity. Dawww... :(  I'll still upvote you if you post it... :)

Comment: Heh, I'll still go for it :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 It’s not enough to just fix the signature of `make_sandwich`. There are two other issues which would pop up as soon as you fix that.

Comment: Hmm... You're right. Though it's arguably more a flaw with the design, I think. You're referring to the signature when the `insides` method will be called inside the decorator, right?

Comment: Eh, I'm too tired to make an answer. Someone can go ahead :) This 16 yr old has too much school work and exams. She needs to get off this site :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 The remaining problems are the signature of the inner function (which needs to take `self`) and the call of `insides`, yes. I detailed that in my answer. And now you go and learn for school ;)

Comment: @poke If only school would stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@make_sandwich
def print_sandwich(self):
    …
```

When you use the decorator syntax like that, then only the function is passed to the decorator. So `make_sandwich` receives only a single argument. But as the error says, it takes exactly two.

So you need to change `make_sandwich` to take only the function reference, not the implicit `self` which is the sandwich instance.

As soon as you do that, you will run into two more issues: The function that is returned from `make_sandwich` does not take any argument, so when you call the decorated `print_sandwich`, the implicit `self` is passed but the function does not take any argument. So you need to change the inner function to take the implcit `self`. The last issue is then that the decorated function will be called without the implicit self. So you need to call it as `insides(self)` to fix that.

The decorator should then look like this:

```
def make_sandwich(insides):
    def add_bread(self):
        self.sandwich.insert(0, self.bread)
        insides(self)
        self.sandwich.append(self.bread)
    return add_bread
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped! Can you tell my why is the self passed into the fuction inside the decorator, and not the decorator itself?

Comment: At the moment you are creating/defining your class, there is no `self`. The `make_sandwich` is executed right when the class definition is “complete” before any instance of it can exist. And since the decorator is not executing in an instance-context but rather “from the outside”, there is no self. But as you may have noticed yourself, this makes `make_sandwich` as a member of your class rather odd. It’s not a `staticmethod`, so every call to it later would result in the class or instance reference being implicitly passed. That’s why you should better move the decorator outside of the class.

Comment: So let me get this straight: the decorator doesn't take the `self` argument because it's being created before the class instance. But the `self` is required when `insides()` is called since the `insides()` is called when an instance already exists, so `self`will be passed to it anyway, right? Does this mean that I cannot use this decorator for fuctions that are not inside classes? If so, is this decorator badly designed?

Comment: `insides` essentially replaces the original `print_sandwich` method. So the new function has to be compatible with the original one. Usually you would use variable arguments and just pass everything on to the original function to make it compatible with everything. But in your case, you are already specific to your type, requiring access to `self.sandwich` and `self.bread`, so that’s a very specialized decorator anyway.

Comment: Great, it finally clicked for me. Thank you, you've been more than helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answers in: [Python class method decorator w/ self arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731136/python-class-method-decorator-w-self-arguments) and [Python decorators in classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263451/python-decorators-in-classes)

If I understand what you're after, I would suggest the following (summarized) approach:

```
class SandwichMaker:
  def make_sandwich(func):
    def inner(self):
        print("do before")
        func(self)
        print("do after")
    return inner

  @make_sandwich
  def print_sandwich(self):
    print("foo")

s = SandwichMaker()
s.print_sandwich()
```