# Decorators on bound methods with access to class and his ancestors

Tags: python, class, reflection, decorator, python-decorators

When I decorated the bound method in Python class, I need get some info in this decorator from outer class. Is that possible?

For example:

```
def modifier(func):
    import sys
    cls_namespace = sys._getframe(1).f_locals
    cls_namespace['data']  # dictonary has no key 'data'
    ...
    return func

class Parent:
    data = "Hi!"

class Child(Parent):

    @modifier
    def method(self):
        pass
```

the `cls_namespace` is just incomplete namespace of current class without `data` field that I need to get.

Is there ways to get it in decorator?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Function decoration takes place when the class body is being executed, nothing is known about the class itself or its base classes at this time. This means that `modifier` decorates the *unbound function object* and only when `func` is actually called on an instance will it be bound.

You could return a wrapper function to replace the decorated function, it'll be bound instead and you'll have access to `self`:

```
from functools import wraps

def modifier(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # self is an instance of the class
        self.data
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

The wrapper will then be called each time `method` is called on an instance.

If you must have access to the *base classes* at class creation time, you'll have to wait until the `class Child` statement has *completed execution*. Until Python 3.6, that's only possible from a class decorator or metaclass; each is called after the class body is created and you'll have access to (at the least) the base classes.

Using a class decorator, for example:

```
def modifier(cls):
    # cls is the newly created class object, including class attributes
    cls.data
    return cls

@modifier
class Child(Parent):
    def method(self):
        pass
```

Note the location of the decorator now.

Python 3.6 adds an [`__init_subclass__` method](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-487-simpler-customization-of-class-creation) that could also give you that access; the (class) method is called each time a subclass is created of the current class:

```
class Parent:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        # cls is a subclass of Parent
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.data

    data = "Hi!"

class Child(Parent):
    def method(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a particularly even solution:

```
def wrap_class(cls):
    """Wrap a class to allow binding all decorated methods."""
    for func in cls.__dict__.values():
        if hasattr(func, '__wrapped__'):
            func.__wrapped__.im_class = cls

    return cls
```

Requires you to use `@functools.wraps(func)` and then to decorate the class with `@wraps_class`.

Decorator example:

```
def decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cls = self.__class__  # bound and straight-forward
        ...

    def extra(*args, **kwargs):
        cls = func.im_class  # Not bound
        ...

    inner.extra = extra

    return inner
```

Usage example:

```
@wrap_class
class Badger:
    @decorator
    def stoat(self, mushroom, snake):
        pass

Badger().stoat()
Badger.stoat.extra()
```

Answer (score -1):

Not that the very first arg passed to your decorator's wrapper will be an objects instance (`self`). Thanks to it you can access w=everything you need.

See Raphaels response: 
[Related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731136/python-class-method-decorator-w-self-arguments)

```
def wrapped(self, *f_args, **f_kwargs):
```

self is the very first argument