# Auto call a method upon instantiating a class

Tags: python, class, oop

I have this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from types import NoneType 


class Alluris(object):

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def log_in(self):
        driver = 
webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\Users\V\Desktop\PY\web_scrape\phantomjs.exe')
        driver.get('https://alluris.han.nl')
        driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(self.username)
        driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(self.password)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*
[@id="formfields"]/input[3]').click()
        soup = BS(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        if type(soup.find('div', {'id' : 'errormessage'})) == NoneType:
            print 'Logged in successfully'
        else:
            print soup.find('div', {'id' : 'errormessage'}).text
```

I want the `log_in` method to auto run when I create an instance of a class, for example:

```
Alluris('username', 'password')
```

Output should be: `Logged in successfully` or `Incorrect username or password`.

I don't want to run the `log_in` method manually like

```
 Alluris('username', 'password').log_in()
```

Comment: You can simply put `self.log_in()` call in your `__init__` method.

Comment: @taras I tried but ut only return the class object.

Comment: If you expect something else to be returned, how would you get the instance of the class?

Comment: @KlausD. I'm sorry but i dont quite understand your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by calling the method in your `__init__` method:

```
class Alluris(object):

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.log_in()
```

Comment: @V.Anh You should probably `print` not `return` in your `log_in`

Comment: It worked, thank you a lot but is there any decorator that allow me to perform the same thing ?

Comment: @V.Anh Why do you need a decorator?

Comment: I'm just curious that's all.

Comment: @V.Anh Decorators are not very difficult to code, only it gets tricky when decorating a class method. You can start from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731136/python-class-method-decorator-w-self-arguments), if you run into any problems, feel free to ask a new question.