# How to store method output at each call in python

Tags: python, decorator

Given the class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = []
        return

    def fitness(self, x):
        return x*x
```

I want to be able to store into the `log` attribute, the output to each call of the `fitness` method. In order to have the following:

```
my_obj = MyClass()

my_obj.fitness(3)
# Expected output 9
my_obj.fitness(6)
# Expected output 36

my_obj.log 
# Expected output [9, 36]
```

I was thinking about a method decorator, but I don't know how to pass the attribute as argument. I need the log attribute to be embedded in the class and not an external variable. 
I am using python 3.

Comment: there is no rule says decorator must refer to an external variable. this must be a duplicated question.

Comment: Just add `self.log.append(x*x)` in the fitness method before you return?

Comment: In `fitness`, store the result of `x * x` in a variable, add that result to the log and then return it.

Comment: Is it acceptable to modify `MyClass.fitness`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python class method decorator w/ self arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731136/python-class-method-decorator-w-self-arguments)

Comment: A decorator would really make sense here only if you wanted to modify the behavior of several methods -- but in that case how would you tell is a given output comes from `fitness` or some other method? If you do want to log multiple methods, a log which is a dictionary keyed by the method names would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a decorator, just edit the `fitness` method to modify the object `log` variable:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = []
        return

    def fitness(self, x):
        self.log.append(x*x)
        return x*x
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is have the fitness method modify the log attribute directly:

```
def fitness(self, x):
    self.log.append(x*x)
```