# Any beautiful way to make tf.function takes in class instance value?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.shape = [None, 4]

    @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=self.shape)])
    def add_constant(self, a):
        print('Building graph')
        return a + 5
```

Any way to make this possible? Currently, I just decorate `add_constant` inside `Foo class __init__` as:

```
self.add_constant = tf.function(func=self.add_constant, input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=self.shape)]).
```

However, this makes the code less readable comparable to function decorator.

Comment: This may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731136/python-class-method-decorator-with-self-arguments

Comment: I've been looking for a solution for this for the whole last day but this is the only one that actually works, 4 years later...