# python use self in decorator for class method

Tags: python, methods, decorator, python-decorators, self

I want to use self.something as a parameter of decorator.
like this:

```
def synchronized(lock):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with lock:
                func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = Lock()

    @synchronized(self.lock)
    def test(self):
        pass
```

but I can't use self in this situation. plz help me.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731136/python-class-method-decorator-with-self-arguments

Comment: Per Thierry Lathuille, does this answer your question? [Python class method decorator with self arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731136/python-class-method-decorator-with-self-arguments)