# TypeError with Validation decorator in class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, python-decorators

I am trying to use a simple validation decorator inside a class:

```
import numpy as np

def validate_decorator(func):
    def func_wrapper(value):
        if value < 0:
            raise Exception("Not valid!")
        return func(value)
    return func_wrapper


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_array = np.zeros(shape=(10,))
        self.idx = 0

    @validate_decorator
    def insert_value(self, value):
        self.my_array[self.idx] = value
        self.idx += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.my_array[:self.idx]}"


a = MyClass()
a.insert_value(3.14)
```

This gives

> TypeError: func_wrapper() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I do not understand this error.

If I modify the `func_wrapper` to also take a `self` argument and `return self` (instead of `func(value)`) then there is no `TypeError` but, as expected, the `insert_value` is not executed.

Can someone help me understand how to use this simple decorator inside my class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731136/python-class-method-decorator-with-self-arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added `self` argument to `func_wrapper` and changed `func_wrapper`'s return value to `func(self, value)`. It works now, `insert_value` is executed.

Class instance method always has this required `self` attribute unless converted to class method or static method: [What is the purpose of the word 'self', in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self-in-python)

```
import numpy as np

def validate_decorator(func):
    def func_wrapper(self, value):
        if value < 0:
            raise Exception("Not valid!")
        return func(self, value)
    return func_wrapper


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_array = np.zeros(shape=(10,))
        self.idx = 0

    @validate_decorator
    def insert_value(self, value):
        self.my_array[self.idx] = value
        self.idx += 1
        print('EXECUTED!')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.my_array[:self.idx]}"


a = MyClass()
a.insert_value(3.14)
```