# Referencing self in decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, python-tenacity

I am implementing a database connector class in python. I will use the `retry` decorator from tenacity library to retry the connection of database when it times out.

I want to pass the `self.retry_count` and `self.retry_interval` to the arguments in `retry` decorator.

```
## etl_connect.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import logging
from tenacity import *

class Connector():
    def __init__(self, mode, conn_str, retry_count, retry_interval):
        self.mode = mode
        self.conn_str = conn_str
        self.retry_count = retry_count
        self.retry_interval = retry_interval
        self.engine = None
        self.conn = None

    @retry(wait=wait_fixed(self.retry_interval), stop=stop_after_attempt(self.retry_count))
    def mysql_connect(self):
        logging.info('Connecting to mysql. (retry count=%d)' % (self.mysql_connect.retry.statistics['attempt_number']))
        mysql_engine = create_engine(self.conn_str)
        mysql_conn = mysql_engine.connect()
        logging.info('Connected to mysql successfully with %d attempt(s).' % (self.mysql_connect.retry.statistics['attempt_number']))
        return (mysql_engine, mysql_conn)
```

Now call the `mysql_connect` function:

```
## call.py
from etl_connect import *
mysql_connector = Connector('mysql', 'mysql database string here', 5, 10)
engine, conn = mysql_connector.mysql_connect()
```

But it shows: `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "call.py", line 5, in <module>
    from etl_connect import *
  File "/home/developer/ETL_modules/etl_connect.py", line 19, in <module>
    class Connector():
  File "/home/developer/ETL_modules/etl_connect.py", line 56, in Connector
    @retry(wait=wait_fixed(self.retry_interval), stop=stop_after_attempt(self.retry_count))
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Are there any ways that I can pass `self.retry_count` & `self.retry_interval` to the decorator?

Comment: Here's the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731136/python-class-method-decorator-with-self-arguments

Comment: Note that answer assumes you are writing the decorator; if `retry` is something you are importing, you would need to define your *own* decorator that wraps it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python class method decorator with self arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731136/python-class-method-decorator-with-self-arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of decorating the method, call `retry` when you *call* the method.

```
## etl_connect.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import logging
from tenacity import *

class Connector():
    def __init__(self, mode, conn_str, retry_count, retry_interval):
        self.mode = mode
        self.conn_str = conn_str
        self.retry_count = retry_count
        self.retry_interval = retry_interval
        self.engine = None
        self.conn = None

    def _mysql_connect(self):
        logging.info('Connecting to mysql. (retry count=%d)' % (self.mysql_connect.retry.statistics['attempt_number']))
        mysql_engine = create_engine(self.conn_str)
        mysql_conn = mysql_engine.connect()
        logging.info('Connected to mysql successfully with %d attempt(s).' % (self.mysql_connect.retry.statistics['attempt_number']))
        return (mysql_engine, mysql_conn)

    def mysql_connect(self):
        d = retry(
              wait=wait_fixed(self.retry_interval),
              stop=stop_after_attempt(self.retry_count)
            )
        # One of these two should work, depending on how
        # retry is actually defined.
        return d(Connector._mysql_connect)(self)
        # return d(self._mysql_connect)
```

Comment: This worked for me. Can you explain why the '(self)' is necessary?

Comment: Which `self` are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying -- the `(self)` in the return statement of mysql_connect.

Comment: In either case, `_mysql_connect` is an instance method, and so needs to be called with or on an instance of `Connector`. Whether you pass it explicitly, or pass a bound method to `retry`, depends on whether `retry` (left undefined in the original question) takes a zero- or 1-argument callable.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the decorator (retry) is defined as part of the class (and is not static) then you cannot reference an object instance in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't access `@retry` decorator and you prevent to edit it you can define a variable out of your class definition. Or you can define this base config in your setting's file then import it. Please look at this:

```
## etl_connect.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import logging
from tenacity import *


base_config = {
    'retry_count': 3,
    'retry_interval': 30,
    ...
}

class Connector():
    def __init__(self, mode, conn_str):
        self.mode = mode
        self.conn_str = conn_str
        self.engine = None
        self.conn = None

    @retry(wait=wait_fixed(base_config['retry_interval']), stop=stop_after_attempt(base_config['retry_count']))
    def mysql_connect(self):
        logging.info('Connecting to mysql. (retry count=%d)' % (self.mysql_connect.retry.statistics['attempt_number']))
        mysql_engine = create_engine(self.conn_str)
        mysql_conn = mysql_engine.connect()
        logging.info('Connected to mysql successfully with %d attempt(s).' % (self.mysql_connect.retry.statistics['attempt_number']))
        return (mysql_engine, mysql_conn)
```

Or import from setting's file:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import logging
from tenacity import *

from settings import RETRY_COUNT
from settings import RETRY_INTERVAL
```

I know this way is solid but these options should define in your settings and no need to pass them every time you want make-instance of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't easily redefine the tenacity `retry` decorator, you could wrap it with one of your own that references the values in the `Connector` instance.

Here's what I mean:

```
# Wrapper for tenacity retry decorator
def my_retry(func):
    def wrapped(conn, *args, **kwargs):
        tdecorator = retry(wait=wait_fixed(conn.retry_interval),
                           stop=stop_after_attempt(conn.retry_count))
        decorated = tdecorator(func)
        return decorated(conn, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped


class Connector():
    def __init__(self, mode, conn_str, retry_count, retry_interval):
        self.mode = mode
        self.conn_str = conn_str
        self.retry_count = retry_count
        self.retry_interval = retry_interval
        self.engine = None
        self.conn = None

    @my_retry
    def mysql_connect(self):
        logging.info('Connecting to mysql. (retry count=%d)' % (self.mysql_connect.retry.statistics['attempt_number']))
        mysql_engine = create_engine(self.conn_str)
        mysql_conn = mysql_engine.connect()
        logging.info('Connected to mysql successfully with %d attempt(s).' % (self.mysql_connect.retry.statistics['attempt_number']))
        return (mysql_engine, mysql_conn)
```