# Python | class method decorator before instantiation

Tags: python, class, oop, decorator, python-decorators

*Foreword: this question is probably simpler than the title may suggest*

I am trying to implement a simple event handler system, using decorators to 'subscribe' various methods and functions to an event.

### 1. Simple approach to event handlers

A simple approach would be to create a class for adding and running the event:

```py
# class for adding and running functions, aka an event handler
class Runner:
    def __init__(self):
        self.functions = []
    def add(self, function):
        self.functions.append(function)
    def run(self):
        for function in self.functions:
            function()

runner = Runner()
```

and then adding various functions or methods:

```py
# random example function
def myFunction():
    print('myFunction')

# random example class
class MyClass:
    def myMethod(self):
        print('myMethod')

# getting instance of class & method
myObject = MyClass()
myObjectMethod = myObject.myMethod

runner.add(myFunction)
runner.add(myObjectMethod)
runner.run()
```

Which leads to:

```sh
> py main.py
myFunction
myMethod
```

Nice! It works as expected

### 2. Decorator approach

So this is okay, but I've recently learned about decorators and thought I could tidy up the syntax by replacing the somewhat ugly `runner.add()` method.

First I change the `Runner.add()` method to work as a decorator:

```py
class Runner:
    def __init__(self):
        self.functions = []
    def add(self, function):
        self.functions.append(function)
        return function # <-- returns function
    def run(self):
        for function in self.functions:
            function()

runner = Runner()
```

Then I remove the `runner.add()` calls and insert the decorator:

```py
@runner.add
def myFunction():
    print('myFunction')

class MyClass:
    @runner.add
    def myMethod(self):
        print('myMethod')

# myObject = MyClass()
# myObjectMethod = myObject.myMethod

runner.run()
```

Which obviously leads to:

```sh
> py main.py
myFunction
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: myMethod() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Clearly the problem here is that I'm adding the 'static' (or is it *'unbound'?*) `myMethod` to the event, which isn't associated with an instance and therefore doesn't have any instance of `self`.

Answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11731136/9063935) one refer to implementing decorators to wrap methods ***as*** they're called, however my reason for using decorators is the access you get upon initial code execution.

A thought is that something would have to run in the `MyClass.__init__()` constructor, since only then has an instance been created and you have access to `self`, but how then how would you run a decorator ***only*** on instantiation? Let alone to achieve the result we're after here.

### The question

What options do I have for implementing behaviour shown in example 1, but with syntax as close as possible to example 2 (or any other 'clean looking' variant perhaps) due to `runner.add()` being kinda verbose, ugly, and certainly not as streamlined as decorators.

Cheers!

Comment: should every instance of `MyClass` that ever gets created be added to the `Runner`?  how do they get removed?  what's wrong with using functions?

Comment: @SamMason Yes, every instance (and subclass even) should have its `myMethod` added to `Runner`. And as mentioned I wanted a cleaner syntax for event subscription - the inline syntax with decorators seems much more preferable.

Comment: why not just put `runner.add(self.myMethod)` in `__init__`?  it makes it more obvious to readers of the code what's going on, and that this will affect every instance.  the only way I can think of making it work would be messing around with metaclasses and involving the `__new__` method.  hopefully somebody else will have an easier idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of treating functions and methods the same, you handle them slightly differently:

**Function:**

- *`[A]`* Add function as normal to list

**Method:**

- An unbound method when the decorator is called, so doesn't have an associated instance or value for `self` yet
- *`[B]`* We 'tag' the method while its unbound (before an instance has been created) by setting its `_tagged` attribute
- *`[C]`* Once an instance has been created (and the `self` variable has been filled), inside `__init__()` we search through and add all tagged methods
- We can add the methods afterwards since once they're bound to an instance the `self` argument is filled (meaning it technically has no parameters, akin to `functools.partial()`)

```py
import inspect

class Runner:
    def __init__(self):
        self.functions = []

    def add(self, function):
        if len(inspect.signature(function).parameters) == 0:
            # [A] adds if has no parameters
            self.functions.append(function)
        else:
            # [B] tags if has 1 parameter (unbound methods have "self" arg)
            function._tagged = True
        return function

    # [C] search through object and add all tagged methods
    def add_all_tagged_methods(self, object):
        for method_name in dir(object):
            method = getattr(object, method_name)
            if hasattr(method, '_tagged'):
                self.functions.append(method)

    def run(self):
        for function in self.functions:
            function()

runner = Runner()
```

Then use the same initial code as below

```py
@runner.add
def myFunction():
    print('myFunction')

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        runner.add_all_tagged_methods(self)

    @runner.add
    def myMethod(self):
        print('myMethod')

myObject = MyClass()
myObjectMethod = myObject.myMethod

runner.run()
```