# Pass instance variables to a wrapper inside a decorator class

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

In a previous question, someone informed me that I could use the `getattr` method to pass instance variables to a decorator function. For example, here I should be able to pass `c` to some_wrapper.

Here is the original question if anyone was interested.
[Passing instance variables to a decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67794959/passing-instance-variables-to-a-decorator)

```
import functools 

def some_func(
   a = False
  ,b = None
):
      def some_decorator(func):
          @functools.wraps(func)
          def some_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
              c = getattr(self, 'c', None)

              ...


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, arg, c=None):
        self.arg = arg
        self.c = c

    @some_func(a=True)    
    def foo(self, x, y):
        ...
```

---

**Edit:**

What the above allows me to do is pass `c` to `some_wrapper` when foo is passed into the decorator. So if I have another method like:

```
    @some_func(a=True)    
    def bar(self, alpha, beta):
        ...
```

`self.c` gets passed onto the other instance methods as well which is what I want.

```
instance = MyClass(arg, c = 'Hi')

instance.foo(arg, blarg)
instance.bar(alpha, beta)
```

However, I decided to go a different route and converted the function decorator into a class decorator. i.e:

```
class SomeClass():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.a = None
        self.b = None
       
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        import functools
        return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)
                

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        def some_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            c = getattr(self, 'c', None)

        ...
        self.func = args[0]
        return some_wrapper
```

`getattr` doesn't work in the same way as I showed in the first example. My stab in the dark guess is that in my second example, the function is no longer passed as as argument anymore, so the `self` in `getattr(self, 'c', None)` no longer reference to the instance from the decorated function.

Is there a work around this?

Comment: I'm not following what you are wanting your decorator to do. Can you explain what your end goal is with a decorator and maybe I can help. A three layer deep decorator is kinda over kill. Usually they are max of 2 layers.

Comment: @Mythalorian: Sure let me revise the question

Comment: So really you already have a working function decorator but you're wanting to migrate it to a class decorator?

Comment: @Mythalorian exactly!

Comment: And the decorator is suppose to inject the value it gets from the class into the function call so that for example `c` is now passed into the func that it decorates?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me :

```py
import functools


def some_func(a=False, b=None):
    def some_decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def some_wrapper(self: "MyClass", *args, **kwargs):
            kwargs.pop("y")
            c = self.c
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs, y=c)
        return some_wrapper
    return some_decorator


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, arg, c=None):
        self.arg = arg
        self.c = c

    @some_func(a=True)
    def foo(self, x, y):
        print(f"foo x={x} y={y}")


no_c = MyClass("arg")
no_c.foo(x=3, y=4)
yes_c = MyClass("blarg", c="I do")
yes_c.foo(x=3, y=4)
```

output :

```
foo x=3 y=None
foo x=3 y=I do
```