# Decorator on class method that execute first the class's method

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I wish to have a decorator on a class method using private fields.
Consider this:

```
class MyDB():

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def open_connection(self):
        print ("open connection for "+self.value)

    def close_connection(self):
        print ("close connection "+self.value)

    def doA(self, request):
        self.open_connection()
        print ("DO A "+request)
        self.close_connection()

    def doB(self):
        self.open_connection()
        print ("DO B")
        self.close_connection()
```

and

```
db = MyDB('remote')
db.doA(request='ABC')
```

will result in:

```
open connection for remote
DO A ABC
close connection remote
```

**So far so good** but you will note the open/close on each method is redundant. What I wish to do is add a wrapper such that:

```
def make_connection(func):
    
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):        
        #self.open_connection() <--this is what I need but how?
        r = func(*args, **kwargs)                            
        #self.close_connection() <--this is what I need but how?
        return r
    
    return wrapper
```

and later I can simply do

```
@make_connection
def doA(self, request): 
    print ("DO A "+request) 

@make_connection
def doB(self): 
    print ("DO B")
```

**What's the problem?**

I couldnt figure how to use the self in the make_connection wrapper. After all, when creating a connection, I need to use self.open_connection and self.close_connection()  (in this dummy example it has value and in the real problem theres much of business going on). I used this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731136/class-method-decorator-with-self-arguments) from SO but couldnt integrate it in my dummy example.

How can I integrate self in a wrapper?

Comment: perhaps use a context manager? https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html

Comment: Python doesn't really have private fields.

Comment: So, note, `self` is just the conventional name we use for the *first positional argument* toa  method, which will implicitly get passed the instance when the method is called on that instance. So here, "self" is `args[0]`. You could do `args[0].open_connection()`, for example

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks; got it. solved.