# Python decorator with self argument: TypeError: function takes 2 positional arguments but 1 were given

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am using a simple function to return the ntp time stored in variable `self._time`. Each time I call this function, I want to send a new ntp request to update the time before returning it by the function (there are other functions that require to query the ntp time as well). I decided to use a decorator for this. The function call looks like this:

```
@_get_time_from_server
def _get_ntp_time(self) -> tuple:
    # Returns ntp time from ntp server.
    return self._time
```

The decorator function looks like that:

```
def _get_time_from_server(self, func):
    # Tries got receive the time from the ntp server.
    # On success, func() will be called.
    # Otherwise, the operation will be aborted.
    # This is a decorator function.
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if self._wifi.is_enabled():
            self._wifi.connect_to_ap()
            # Check if we are connected.
            if self._wifi.is_connected_to_ap():
                # Query NTP Server.
                log.info('Querying NTP Server.')
                res = self._query_server()
                if res:
                    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    log.warning('Could not retrieve time from NTP server.')
                    return
            return
       return
    return wrapper
```

Calling `self._query_server()` will update `self._time`.

When I call the `_get_ntp_time()` function, I get the following error message:

> TypeError: function takes 2 positional arguments but 1 were given

I did not really find lots of examples using the self parameter within a decorator function. But I need to do this since I am accessing some instance attributes. I played around with the self parameter, but did not find any solution.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731136/class-method-decorator-with-self-arguments) but could not manage to solve my problem.

I'm new to decorator functions, but it seems to be a suitable use case for me. Am I doing something basically wrong?

Stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 28, in <module>
File "timing.py", line 49, in <module>
File "timing.py", line 117, in Timing
TypeError: function takes 2 positional arguments but 1 were given
MicroPython v1.19.1-932-g6bb60745b on 2023-03-07; ESP32S3 module (spiram) with ESP32S3
```

Line 117 is "@_get_time_from_server"

Comment: Provide the full stacktrace.

Comment: `_get_time_from_server` doesn't receive two parameters, so you shouldn't even get to the part where you call `_get_ntp_time`.

Comment: @MegaIng: How would I do this? What's basically wrong?

Comment: @Sebastian My primary point is that your error analysis in your post was wrong to the point of being confusing. See the answer by Daraan for how to use `self`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
@decorator
def foo(self):
   return self.a+1
```

is basically the same as

```
foo = decorator(lambda self.a: self.a+1)
```

Your decorator will only get the function as its only argument (sitenote: there are other ways to define decorators that can get multiple arguments)

```
def _get_time_from_server(func): # only function as parameter
    # Tries got receive the time from the ntp server.
    # On success, func() will be called.
    # Otherwise, the operation will be aborted.
    # This is a decorator function.
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs): # <--- here self is passed
        if self._wifi.is_enabled():
            self._wifi.connect_to_ap()
            # Check if we are connected.
            if self._wifi.is_connected_to_ap():
                # Query NTP Server.
                log.info('Querying NTP Server.')
                res = self._query_server()
                if res:
                    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    log.warning('Could not retrieve time from NTP server.')
                    return
            return
        return
    return wrapper
```