# Get class of method in decorator

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to get the class a method is defined inside a decorator:

```py
from types import MethodType
def decorate(func: MethodType):
    """Given a method, try to get the
    class the method is in"""
    print(func.__class__.__name__)
    return func

class BaseClass:
    @decorate
    def foo(self):
        '''This should print BaseClass'''

class ShowExample(BaseClass):
    @decorate
    def bar(self):
        '''This should print ShowExample'''
```

However, this just prints

```bash
function
function
```

Maybe this is possible with the `inspect` package, but I'm not sure where to start looking as my Google searches turned up nothing.

Comment: This might be tricky, since the function doesn't, I think, technically belong to any class at that point yet (it's just in the class's namespace dict)...

Comment: You can get the class name with `func.__qualname__.rpartition(".")[0]`, in any case, but not  a reference to the class object itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class method decorator with self arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731136/class-method-decorator-with-self-arguments) *(Allows `print(self.__class__.__name__)`)*

Comment: use AKX comment with `globals()` and by adding a decorator with parameters for the function/method you are decorating

Comment: I don't think you can access to the class at the time the syntactic-sugar decoration is executed

Comment: Do you want those values to print when foo and bar are executed, or when the decorator is envoked?